# Call same function inside function gives "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm calling a function `sync_thing()` that gives me the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: sync_thing is not a function

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var sync_counter = 0;
  sync_thing();
  function sync_thing() {
    var sync_thing = $.ajax({
      url: '../there_be_the_functions/sync_thingy.php',
      success: function(response) {
        if (response != 'done') { // added later to clarify that it's not infinite loop
          sync_thing();
        }
      }
    }); 
  }
});
```

Comment: `var sync_thing = $.ajax` is your problem.

Comment: Even if you fix it you create an eternal loop (if ajax success)

Comment: @yezzz It's part of a thing that relies on a response so it's not really eternal. I didn't include all the code here.

Comment: ok I thought you should be aware... which you are ;)

Comment: I try to be :) Thanks though

Comment: Thanks a bundle guys. There seems to be lots of good suggestions here. It's kids' bedtime now, so I'll look into it in 14 hours and give feedback. Nice downvotes, btw :) Probably on the spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things happen here

1. You are replacing `sync_thing` function to  `var sync_thing = $.ajax({` which changes `sync_thing` defination and throw error when you call
2. It is creating infinite call of `sync_thing` if you get `success` every time.

Comment: Is not replacing anything. That function still exists and can be used anywhere else still. It is a variable scope issue

Comment: Yes It is not replacing outside the  `sync_thing` but It will change definition  when you access `sync_thing` from `success` function.

Comment: Right but explanation is confusing and a bit misleading

Answer (score 1):

You are re-defining `sync_thing` *inside* the function.
look at

```
function sync_thing(){
    var sync_thing = {};
    //sync_thing is no longer a function at this point
}
```